# Dart - applying a class to an element does not have an immediate effect

Tags: css, dart

I am using Dart and polymer. I want to apply a style to an element (following a user selection,for example). This method works immediately:

```
tablecell.style.borderTopColor='red';
```

But if I use a class:

```
tablecell.classes.add("myclass");
```

this does not work immediately - until I rebuild the whole (expensive) table (so I know it has accepted the class).
First, is that a bug? Should it work? Or, is there someway to refresh just that one cell/element? I thought maybe with a dispatchEvent, but I don't know which event to use. Can it be done? like

```
cell.refresh();
table.refresh();
table.dispatchevent(blur);
```

Cheers, Steve

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should just work.

Comment: This surely works. Post more code please.

Comment: Have you checked the code is actually executed?